# Super contributions splitting

Tags: australia, superannuation

I came across contributions splitting recently. So my employer contributions go into my super account and I believe they’re taxed 15%.
If I choose to contributions splitting which is max 85% of previous financial year’s employer compulsory concessional contribution into my spouse’ super fund will she get taxed 15% too?

Comment: Different countries do it differently. Please add a country tag to your question.

Comment: My bad to not mention. Im in Australia.

Comment: Weird that the ATO website doesn't make this explicit. My guess is that it gets taxed once going into your super and then the transfer from yours into your spouce's super is tax free. Can't find a source to verify, so this is a comment, not an answer